# Q: Given $n$ is a positive integer greater than 2 prove that....

Tags: number-theory

> i) $10201_n$ (Small $n$ btw for base) is a square number [2 marks]
>
> ii) $1221_n$ is a composite number [5 marks]

for i) I used $n$ to get its equal to $(n^2 + 1)^2$ but I'm not sure If I need to use, $n = 2k+1$ in replacement of $n$ when working to show I am proving for positive integers.

for ii) I haven't gone past for converting the question into powers of $n$.

How would I solve these questions?

Comment: For i, you don't need $n=2k+1$. $2k+1$ is used for odd numbers, not positive integers. For ii, factorize the expression once you expressed $1221_n$ as a sum of powers of $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need to use $n=2k+1$ since $10201_n=(n^2+1)^2$ is valid for all $n>2$.
2. $1221_n=n^3+2(n^2+n)+1=(n+1)^3-n(n+1)=(n+1)(n^2+n+1)$ is divisible by $(n+1)\ne1,1221_n$.

Comment: I bugged out on the first one, completely misread the question.

Comment: but can you explain to me how it means its composite?

Comment: To show composite, you need to find a factor of $1221_n$ other than $1$ and itself. That factor is $(n+1)$.

Comment: I think I get it (n+1) as n>5 it must be > 6 and less than n otherwise (n^2+n+1) > 1221n as (n+1)<(n^2+n+1) which is impossible so must be some other factor than n and 1.  6 < (n+1) < n. Though I guess you would never write this long-winded explanation in a exam.

Comment: Since $n>2,n+1>3$ so $n+1\ne1$. Further, $1221_n=(n+1)(n^2+n+1)>n+1$ since $n^2+n+1>1$ for $n>2$. So $n+1\ne1221_n$.